# php artisan migrate error | Illuminate\Database\QueryException | could not find driver | Windows 10 Pro | MAMP PRO 5 + Laravel 9.x

Tags: php, laravel, mysql-connector, mamp-pro

**Hello, everyone!** I want to ask a question about **error** I get with command **php artisan migrate**.

So here's the **error** itself:

```
  Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel_app_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\MAMP\htdocs\laravel_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:759
    755▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    756▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    757▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    758▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 759▕             throw new QueryException(
    760▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    761▕             );
    762▕         }
    763▕     }

  1   C:\MAMP\htdocs\laravel_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\MAMP\htdocs\laravel_app\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889;dbname=laravel_app_db", "root", "root", [])
```

I'm on **Windows 10 Pro** and I got **PHP version 8.1.0** and **MAMP PRO 5**.

**MySQL settings** in **MAMP PRO 5**:

[image: MySQL settings in MAMP PRO 5]

**Ports settings** in **MAMP PRO 5**:

[image: Apache settings in MAMP PRO 5]

Created database in **phpMyAdmin**:

[image: Database in phpMyAdmin]

I was watching the 3 hour Laravel tutorial and got stuck on the moment, where the guy was migrating tables by **php artisan migrate** command. I successfully installed Laravel and created a bunch of pages there.

**Here's what I did trying to solve the problem:**

- **enabled php_openssl.dll**, **extension=php_mysqli.dll** and **extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll** extensions in **php.ini** file from this **path** `C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0`
- **changed** DB_HOST, DB_PORT, DB_DATABASE, DB_USERNAME and DB_USERNAME in **.env** file
- **edited AppServiceProvider.php** file like you will see **down below**
- **edited database.php** file like you will see **below AppServiceProvider.php** file

Literally **NOTHING** happens, I still get the error! Maybe I have **wrong PHP version**. Maybe this guy uses **XAMPP local web-server instead of MAMP PRO 5**. I really don't know what to do.

**AppServiceProvider.php** file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema; //<---- added this line

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191); //<---- added this line
    }
}
```

**MySQL properties** from **database.php** file:

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '8889'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'laravel_app_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

**Additional info:**

**Needed extensions** from **php.ini** file:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_gd.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll 
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_imagick.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_apc.dll
;extension=php_apcu.dll
;extension=php_eaccelerator.dll
;extension=php_xcache.dll
;zend_extension=php_opcache.dll
```

**Database properties** from **.env** file:

```
APP_NAME=laravel_app
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:TIlPzLirZ+9Jw6Am0m4XDEodGxmbc8wXSAKQ0XDb5fU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=laravel_app_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Comment: Did `DB_HOST=localhost` solve your problem?

Comment: @WahyuKristianto, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fixed this.

I read those posts:

1. [First post to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34212578/how-do-i-install-pdo-drivers-for-php-on-windows)
2. [Second post to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30182984/sqlstatehy000-2002-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-or-ser)

What did I do:

- I changed **544 line** in `php.ini` from this `extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php5.5.0\ext\"` to this `extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext"`
- Then I got the error from the second post **SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**
- I solved the second error by running this command `php artisan config:clear`
- And then I finally got successful message from cmd

[image: success_msg]

[image: success_db]